# How should a library source file reference a string resource in its parent project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just made my game app into a library so that I can incorporate it into a variety of "wrapper" projects, each with their own manifest file. This is so that I can easily maintain a variety of different versions e.g. free, paid, alternative markets etc.

I also wanted each wrapper to be able to affect the value of various boolean flags like `include_adverts` or `allow_feature_x`. I thought that a good way to do this (correct me if this is a dumb idea) would be for each wrapper project to have its own set of strings defined in its own strings.xml. So it could have things like:

```
<string name="allow_feature_x">true</string>
```

But now I have a problem scooping these strings from within the library.

I tried this:

```
boolean allow_feature_x = my_str2bool(getString(R.string.allow_feature_x));
```

But I get a allow_feature_x cannot be resolve error.
Can this strings.xml thing be made to work? Or was my scheme fundamentally flawed from the start?

Comment: depends on which engine you develop your game. Have you library project (core of game) and UI Android project?

Comment: The engine and UI are NOT separated. I have almost everything inside the library. I just want the wrapper project (that includes my library) to be able to set a few flags and have a custom manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what I do for many of my projects.

Just make sure your library project has all the default set of strings defined in it, otherwise you won't be able to reference them, since the library does not know about the "parent".

Then override them in your "parent" projects. You only need to override the ones that are different from default, otherwise it will take the value from the library project.

Hope that makes sense.

**Edit:** By the way you can reference booleans like so:

```
<bool name="allow_feature_x">true</bool>
```

and then access `getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.allow_feature_x);`

Comment: Yes, but what does the code look like in the library? My getString(R.string.allow_feature_x) would not compile.

Comment: That's odd. Mine looks like that. My understanding is `R` is first generated for the library. Are you referencing the right `R`?

Comment: By the way, if it's a boolean you can reference it through `R.bool`

Comment: I probably am referencing the wrong R. But I don't know how to make sure I'm referencing the correct R.

Comment: Make sure your `R` import at the top is for `com.yourlibrarypackage.R;` Alternatively as a test see if you can access it directly in your code via `com.yourlibrarypackage.R.string.allow_feature_x`

Comment: I think we are talking back to front!.. I want the library to be able to read the resources from the parent project, not the other way round. Maybe this is impossible?

Comment: Like I said, define your defaults in your library. Override them in the project that uses the library. During runtime, the overriden ones will take precedence. It will "find" them. Our terminology is different. I consider the library the "parent" and the one that uses it is the "child" :) But I think what you ask is possible, and it's what I do.